# Customize WPForms dropdown list with WPDatabase

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, wpforms

I have a WPForms form on my website. I want the dropdown to be filled with a list from 1-140 when a number is selected and the form is submitted, the number should disappear from the list. To make this work I want to store the selected numbers in the wordpress database.
However, I always get this error message:

https://www.offroad-dragrace.ch/wordpress/index.php/anmelden/%3C?php%20echo%20admin_url(%27admin-ajax.php%27);%20?%3E 404
(anonymous) @ (index):284
fetchSelectedNumbers @ (index):270
(anonymous) @ (index):292
(index):304

Error retrieving the selected numbers: Error: error retrieving the selected numbers.
at xhr.onload ((index):278:28)
(

Hope someone can help me.

PHP

```
function custom_dropdown() {
    // Die Shortcode-Ausgabe sollte leer sein, da wir das Dropdown-Menü mit JavaScript erstellen.
}

add_shortcode('custom_dropdown', 'custom_dropdown');

function create_selected_numbers_table() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'selected_numbers';
    $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE {$table_name} (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        number smallint NOT NULL,
        UNIQUE KEY id (id)
    ) {$charset_collate};";

    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    dbDelta($sql);
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'create_selected_numbers_table');

function get_selected_numbers() {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'selected_numbers';
    $selected_numbers = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT number FROM {$table_name}");
    wp_send_json($selected_numbers);
}

add_action('wp_ajax_get_selected_numbers', 'get_selected_numbers');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_selected_numbers', 'get_selected_numbers');
```

HTML/JS

```
<!-- Dropdown HTML -->
<div>
    <select id="number-dropdown">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Wählen Sie eine Zahl</option>
        <!-- Optionen werden dynamisch von JavaScript erstellt -->
    </select>
</div>

<!-- AJAX-Anfrage, um die ausgewählten Zahlen abzurufen -->
<script>
    var adminAjaxUrl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
    
    function fetchSelectedNumbers() {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', adminAjaxUrl, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xhr.onload = function () {
                if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
                    resolve(JSON.parse(this.response));
                } else {
                    reject(new Error('Fehler beim Abrufen der ausgewählten Zahlen.'));
                }
            };
            xhr.onerror = function () {
                reject(new Error('Fehler beim Abrufen der ausgewählten Zahlen.'));
            };
            xhr.send('action=get_selected_numbers');
        });
    }
    
    var hiddenFieldID = 'wpforms-531-field_82';
    var dropdown = document.getElementById('number-dropdown');
    var hiddenField = document.getElementById(hiddenFieldID);
    
    fetchSelectedNumbers()
        .then(function (selectedNumbers) {
            for (var i = 1; i <= 140; i++) {
                if (selectedNumbers.indexOf(i) === -1) {
                    var option = document.createElement('option');
                    option.value = i;
                    option.textContent = i;
                    dropdown.appendChild(option);
                }
            }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.error('Fehler beim Abrufen der ausgewählten Zahlen:', error);
        });
    
    dropdown.addEventListener('change', function () {
        hiddenField.value = this.value;
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: The fact that your URL you are making the request to, still _literally_ contains `<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>` (with additional URL encoding applied), did not make you realize that this PHP code simply did not get executed at all ...? (_Because_ you apparently put it into an HTML context, in which no PHP gets parsed.)

Comment: @CBroe Can you also tell me what I should do differently? 
I am not yet so versed in programming.

Comment: Well your "HTML/JS" would have to be in a context where PHP actually gets interpreted. I have no idea how you have currently actually integrated this into your WordPress.